# convert string to nested list with Python

Tags: list, python-3.x

Short question, how do I make this conversion using Python?

```
a["1-3-6-3-6"] ---> a[1][3][6][3][6]
```

I have a nested list and I want to be able to get the item, directly from a string argument passed to the method.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, since `a[1][3][6][3][6]` is not exactly a list.

Comment: I've edited the question, hope it makes more sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> path = '1-3-6-3-6'
>>> element = a
>>> for segment in path.split('-'):
        element = element[int(segment)]
```

After that, `element` equals to whatever was at `a[1][3][6][3][6]`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want

```
>>> i="1-3-6-3-6"
>>> b=i.split("-")
>>> b
['1', '3', '6', '3', '6']
```

Then you can use the indices inside b to descend into your nested list by recursion.